# No TypeTag available

Tags: apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I've tried to make a generic function `diff` (like a function diff in R language) which make a difference vector of given DataFrame's target column according to given binary function, like this:

- given data: `df(col1, col2)`

  Seq(
   ("A", 1),
   ("A", 1),
   ("A", 5),
   ("B", 1),
   ("B", 3)).toDF
- given binary function: `f`

  (x: Int, y: Int) => y - x
- `diff(df, "col1", "col2", f, 0)`
- result

  Seq(
   ("A", 1, 0),
   ("A", 1, 0),
   ("A", 5, 4),
   ("B", 1, 0),
   ("B", 3, 2)).toDF

key difference with `diff` in R is "it works `group by` manner"

anyway, on compile, there occurs an error like this

`Error:(41, 22) No TypeTag available for Array[B]
    val funcUdf = udf(func)`

and something like `udf[Array[B], Array[A]](seqFuncApply)` is not a solution...

```
  import org.apache.spark.sql._
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
  import scala.reflect.ClassTag

  val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("sparksql").master("local").getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._

  def diff[A: ClassTag, B: ClassTag](df: DataFrame, key: String, target: String, diffFunc: (A, A) => B, zero: B) = {

    val seqFuncApply =
      (xs: Array[A]) => {
        if (xs.length < 2) Array(zero)
        else xs.tail.zipWithIndex.map { tu =>
          val x2 = tu._1
          val idx: Int = tu._2
          val x1 = xs.init(idx)
          diffFunc(x2, x1)
        }.+:(zero)
      }

    val funcUdf = udf(seqFuncApply)

    val resultDf: DataFrame =
      df.select(key, target)
        .rdd
        .map(row => (row.getAs[A](0), row.getAs[A](1)))
        .aggregateByKey(Array[A]())(_ :+ _, _ ++ _)
        .toDF(key, target)
        .withColumn("diff_" + target, funcUdf(col(target)))

    val cbind: (DataFrame, DataFrame) => DataFrame =
      (df, df2) => {
        val x =
          df.withColumn("primaryKeyForCbind", monotonically_increasing_id())
            .withColumn("orderKeyForCbind", monotonically_increasing_id()).as("df")
        val y =
          df2.withColumn("primaryKeyForCbind", monotonically_increasing_id()).as("df2")
        x.join(y, col("df.primaryKeyForCbind") === col("df2.primaryKeyForCbind"))
          .sort("orderKeyForCbind")
          .drop("primaryKeyForCbind", "orderKeyForCbind")
      }

    cbind(
      resultDf.select(col(key), explode(col(target))).as("target"),
      resultDf.select(explode(col("diff_" + target)).as("diff_" + target)))
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define `diff`'s generic type `A` with `TypeTag` not `ClassTag`:

```
 def diff[A: ClassTag, B: ClassTag]
```

since `udf` method is expecting `TypeTag` for generic types.

PS: this error should throw in compile time.

Comment: if I change ClassTag -> TypeTag then `Error:(20, 33) No ClassTag available for B
        if (xs.length < 2) Array(zero)` occurs...

Comment: and if I change ClassTag -> TypeTag `A` only then `Error:(29, 22) No TypeTag available for Array[B]
    val funcUdf = udf(seqFuncApply)` occurs...

Comment: so you can bind `ClassTag` too, ` def diff[A: TypeTag:ClassTag, B: TypeTag:ClassTag]`